# Quick setup bootstrap calendar

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to setup [bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar), but I am having some difficulties. I used the command

```
$ bower install bootstrap-calendar
```

to download the dependences and I created a test index file which looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>calendar test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap-calendar/js/language/en-GB.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap-calendar/js/calendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap-calendar/css/calendar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Opening index.html with a browser, gives an empty page. Any idea why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I opened a ticket on GitHub: https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar/issues/166
There was a suggestion to move the script where I select the #calendar, after the html declaration of the div, and also include the event_source parameter. It didn't work, still blank page.

Comment: The order is wrong. And you have to see in browser console and see what are errors.

Comment: Your comment doesn't help, if you check the link in github that I posted, you'll see that the order is actually wrong as you said but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: There is working version in `index.html` in the project. Just delete all you do not need there. Also you have to pass `events_source` parameter as it is mandatory. In any case I believe if you look into javascript console you will have error message text there.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that simply the order which you include your scripts is wrong. I usually put jQuery on top (considering most things are dependent upon it, it will need to be loaded first) then bootstrap.js below it, then underscore, so on and so forth. Scripts should also be included at the end of the body for speed, although it could also be possible that your scripts are running in the head before the dom is loaded, and #calendar is not found simply because it's not there yet. Try those things, good luck!